# Listview.builder inside Sliver

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I had a List of dynamic List of `ListTile` widgets and I wanted to load it lazily, i.e. `ListTile` will be built only when the user scrolls to that position. And I achieved it using `ListView.builder()`, and it was working fine for me.

But, when I wrapped that `ListView.builder()` in `SliverList` using `SliverChildListDelegate`, the lazy loading property of `Listview.builder()` is not working any more, now the whole Listview is built during initialization only, instead of being built lazily.

I want lazy loading in `Listview.builder()` even after wrapping it with `SliverList`. How can I achieve that?

The code before wrapping into SliverList:-

```
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if (index == 0) return userLocationWidget;
          return ListTile(items[index]);
        },
      ),
```

The code after warping it into SliverList:-

```
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.length + 1,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    if (index == 0) return userLocationWidget;
                    return makeCard(items[index - 1]);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: use `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` , not `SliverChildListDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

You can used following code:

```
   SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          [
           SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                child:ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: items.length + 1,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    if (index == 0) return userLocationWidget;
                    return makeCard(items[index - 1]);
                  },
                ),),
            )                   
       ],
    ),
)
```

Comment: Be careful at using SRINKWRAP it makes your data all loaded at once instead of lazily loaded